# ¿Cambiar formato de fecha "31/12/2018 0:00:00" a "2018-12-31" CON PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Soy nuevo manejando fechas con PHP y necesito convertir varios formatos de fecha de este tipo:

```
31/12/2018  0:00:00
```

a este:

```
2018-12-31
```

Me gustaría saber como darle formato a las fechas de forma automática independientemente el tipo de fecha que se este ingresando para luego guardarlo en una base datos Mysql.

lo he estado realizando de esta manera:

```
$fecha_entrada = "31/12/2018 0:00:00";

        $newDate = new DateTime($fecha_entrada);                
       echo($newDate->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Comment: Si lo estaba haciendo con la función "format" y no me quiere darme el formato igual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cambiando el / a - funciona, por el formato de la fecha:
Con str_replace se puede reemplazar el caracter.

```
   <?php
        $fecha = '31/12/2018 00:00:00';
        $fechaModificada  = str_replace("/", "-", $fecha);
        $date = new DateTime($fechaModificada);
        echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
    ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta respuesta promueve una mala práctica, str_replace no debe ser usado en estos casos, es una forma burda de forzar el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando el método [`createFromFormat($format, $time)`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) de la clase `DateTime()` en donde el primer parámetro es el formato de la fecha ingresada y el segundo es la fecha. Por ejemplo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$date = '31/12/2018  0:00:00';
$newDate = new DateTime();
$newDate = $newDate->createFromFormat('d/m/Y  H:i:s', $date);

// aplico el nuevo formato
$newFormat = $newDate->format('Y-m-d');

// imprime: 2018-12-31
var_dump($newFormat);
```

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada. +1

Answer (score 1):

Convierte el formato de fecha con createFromFormat()

```
<?php
$fecha_entrada = "31/12/2018 0:00:00";
$cdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y G:i:s', $fecha_entrada);
echo $cdate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Ten cuidado si tu formato de día no tiene ceros iniciales si el día es menor que 10, lo mismo para el mes y la hora.
Cambia los parámetros al formato correcto siguiendo [esta tabla](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)